# License for incorporating game-play and characters of a video-game in a novel?

Tags: copyright, videogame

I have recently finished my first novel, entitled 'K: A Tale of the Afterlife'. In this novel, there's a certain chapter where the main character walks into an old-fashioned arcade and plays the video-game "Mortal Kombat 3".

As he plays the game, I incorporate the game-play to make the reader feel like he's playing the game with the character. Like the text that appears when you start to play, or the sentences that appear after you win a fight.

"SCORPION WINS!"

"FLAWLESS VICTORY!", etc...

I also mention the names of certain characters in the game, like Scorpion, Sub-Zero, Kitana, etc...

I'm presuming that I need the permission from Warner Bros. Interactive Entertainment (who owns the rights to Mortal Kombat nowadays), but have no idea how to go about it. I haven't found any information about licensing game-play (plenty of info on song-lyrics, but not so much on videogames).

On the Warner Bros. website, it only mentions a phone-number, which I can't call from Belgium, where I'm located. They have information about plenty of their products and what to do if you want to license them, but not on their video-games.

Does anyone have previous experience with this that they can share? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consult a lawyer about the passage. It might be easier and less risky to invent your own arcade game.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say that creating a basic 'variation' of the game would be much easier, and much less intimidating than attempting to acquire rights. If you're adamant, however, on using that particular title, I'd suggest enquiring wbcpinquiries@warnerbros.com, the general licensing advisory of Warner. They may not be able to directly help you however, you may be put through to Warner Game, or Warner entertainment to speak further. I'd also suggest, if you are able to, make use of a lawyer, who has experience in licensing products (be it brands or things of that sort) for books.